# Is it possible to implement UTM tracking on Facebook App Install Ads?

Tags: facebook, ads, utm

I've been trying to track the campaigns, ad sets, and ads from Facebook ads on GA however, under the ads setting in Facebook ads manager, I'm unable to find the 'URL parameters' field to add the UTM link.

Also, can we create a custom audience to retarget Facebook app users that have uninstalled the app? I've been told by the developers that it's not possible to track those users and that we can only track app installs and in-app actions.

Is there any way to implement UTM tracking?

Secondly, I've been told by the developers that it's not possible to track app uninstall users and that we can only track app installs and in-app actions.